# Linux desktop screen full black with dock, wallpaper, panel all gone but still somewhat functional

Tags: arch-linux, plasma, bugs, kde-neon, garuda-linux

Everything was working perfectly fine till yesterday night but when I booted into my Garuda linux today, desktop was pitch black with nothing related to it working. When I first booted, the grub was working fine, the login screen worked too and even the lock screen. However, the desktop is full black with all docks, panels, widgets, wallpapers gone. It shows for a blink after login but disappears. The strange thing is that cursor is visible and works. I can also run apps with the help of krunner.

But the windows key, brightness, audio volume, and things related to desktop doesn’t work. I don’t know what the problem is. I haven’t really tinkered with the settings at all these past few days. All I did was update the system yesterday night after finishing my work and shut it down after update. Is this a bug or something?

P.S.: I do doubt that the problem is with the plasma but I’m not sure. I think so because the plasma notifications are not working either and I see that desktop session: plasma x11 options at the bottom left corner of my login screen which I’m not sure if it was always there.

This is my main machine and I am having a bit of trouble here. So I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

[image: lock screen working]

[image: black screen]

[image: new menu in login screen]

[image: programs run with krunner]

Comment: So the Deepin DE works? Both X11 and Wayland?